# Does 68–95–99.7 rule apply to skewed distributions as well and are they statistically correct?

Tags: normal-distribution, confidence-interval, skewness, skew-normal-distribution

I am not much familiar with statistics, but for my current simulation, I am using it to analyze my results from Monte-Carlo simulation.

I understand the 68–95–99.7 rule. However, I want to confirm (and if any reference please) if the same rule applies to the Skewed curves as well. Please see the attached diagram. In figure 2 (For **Access link**), can I implement the 68–95–99.7 rule to find where does 95% data lies, and will it be statistically correct?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the rule is specific to normal distributions and need not apply to any non-normal distribution, skewed or otherwise. Consider for example the uniform distribution on $[0, 1]$. The SD is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{12}}$, or about .29. Only about 58% of the mass of this distribution is within 1 SD of the mean (0.5).

Comment: Then how can I find 95% data categories in the skewed curve?

Comment: It can also be applied approximately to bell-shape/ mound-shaped symmetric distributions that are close to normal

Comment: @Kashan , are you familiar with quantiles or percentiles?  These could be used to identify the values that encapsulate 95% of the data.  It would require a little cleverness to get the mean in the middle of the spread --- instead of the median --- if that's your goal.

Comment: @Sal Mangiafico:  Yes I am a bit familiar with percentiles. I do not want mean in the middle of the spread. All I want is 95% interval for the Skewed distribution of attached figure. I will appreciate if you can elaborate a bit on this? Meanwhile, since the other two results I have are normal distribution, I have found 95% interval quite easily. I want to stick to it for the skewed graph as well. I will look into percentiles as you mentioned.

Comment: @Kashan , for a given data set, there are many ranges that encapsulate 95% of the data.  For example, there's the lowest 95% of data, the highest 95% of data, 95% of data with the median in the center,  95% of data with the mean in the center, and many others.

Comment: I am looking for highest 95% of data (I think it will make 5th percentile, right). I have reposted this question here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/349811/in-a-left-skewed-distribution-how-can-the-range-where-95-data-lies

Comment: With substantial backing from teachers of statistics, I beg to differ with this opinion. Although the 68-95-99.7 rule of thumb is derived from the Normal distribution, and there are datasets and distributions that depart substantially from it, in practice it applies to a great deal of distributions and data, including strongly non-normal ones. It is definitely intended to apply beyond situations where the data are supposed to have a Normal distribution. For the distributions displayed in the question, this rule should offer reasonable guidance. Nobody would use it to obtain an exact solution.

Comment: @whuber I was under the impression that the 68-95-99.7 rule says that .68 of the mass of the distribution (exact to the nearest hundredth) lies within 1 SD of the mean, and so on. This clearly need not be true for non-normal distributions. If the rule says something more sophisticated, or more vague, I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: You appear to be committing a logical fallacy.  The 68-95-99.7 rule holds for far more than Normal distributions (albeit not all of them).  Observing that it does not hold for some distributions does not contradict this fact.  The primary assertion of your answer--namely, that this rule holds *only* for Normal distributions--is incorrect.

Comment: @whuber I said that the rule "need not apply to any non-normal distribution". No doubt you can construct non-normal distributions where it holds, but normality is what guarantees it. If there is a more general and useful condition than normality that suffices to make the rule work, then I don't know what it is.

Comment: The entire point to this rule of thumb is that it applies to many distributions, not just Normal ones.  Unless your data are extremely long tailed or extremely skewed, it tends to work surprisingly well.  The reason is that even with skewed distributions, the loss or gain of some probability between $-1$ and $0$ sds from the mean is nearly compensated by a counterbalancing gain or loss of probability between $0$ and $1$ sds.

Comment: @whuber It sounds like you're saying both that it applies in more general conditions than normality, and that its statement is less specific than "exactly .68 (to the nearest hundredth) of the mass is within 1 SD of the mean", etc. Again, in that case, I don't know what exactly the condition or statement would be.

Comment: Yes, your interpretation is correct.  This is meant to be general guidance, not a precise quantitative prediction.  After all, even random samples from Normal distributions rarely exhibit exactly these ratios, either.  A more elaborate way to state this rule might be "When you are looking at data, in many cases about two-thirds of the values will be within one SD of their mean, about 19/20s will be within two SDs, and virtually all will be within three SDs." Of course there are exceptions: and they are readily identified because they obviously depart from this description!