# In a left skewed distribution, how can the range where 95% data lies?

Tags: confidence-interval, skewness, heavy-tailed

In a simulation that I ran, I have the following graph as a result. How can I find the 95% confidence interval (i.e. the range where 95% of data lies for me).
Since I am not expert in stats, please do not mark my question if it is silly or very straightforward. I have done my homework and since I do not understand I have turned towards this forum. A similar question of mine can be found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/349808/does-68-95-99-7-rule-apply-to-skewed-distributions-as-well-and-are-they-statisti/349809?noredirect=1#comment659245_349809)

[image]

size of data set  = 1 million

median = 0.1781

mean = 0.1774

standard deviation = 0.0023 (not sure if it is of any interest)

Comment: Sort the data and eliminate the 5% farthest from the mean; the minimum and maximum of what's left form your 95% confidence interval.

Comment: 1. An interval for *data* is not a confidence interval. 2. There are many ways to find an interval containing 95% of the data. You might take the smallest 95% of the values; the largest 95% of the values, the *middle* 95% of the values (i.e. leave 2.5% out each end), the *shortest* interval containing 95% of the values, and so on. 3. As it stands your question is a little vague/broad. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Actually, it looks like this has been addressed in some detail at your *other* question. Please address in your question how the discussion there has failed to resolve your problem.